# Polymorphic QSharedPointer

Tags: c++, qt, polymorphism, type-conversion, casting

I'm trying to use `QSharedPointer` in my polymorphic stucture, but I couldn't find right syntax to convert pointer of base class to pointer of derived class.

```
struct Switch : State {
 int a;
};

QSharedPointer <State> myState=QSharedPointer <State>(new Switch);  

QSharedPointer <Switch> mySwitchTest= ??? myState;
```

What should I put in the place of ???

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [`qSharedPointerCast()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsharedpointer.html#qSharedPointerCast):

```
QSharedPointer <Switch> mySwitchTest= qSharedPointerCast<Switch>(myState);
```

Or call [`staticCast()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsharedpointer.html#staticCast) on the smart pointer:

```
QSharedPointer <Switch> mySwitchTest= myState.staticCast<Switch>();
```

Both versions are basically equivalent to doing `static_cast` on raw pointers.

Answer (score 13):

For a dynamic cast, use qSharedPointerDynamicCast:

```
class Derived : public Base { ... };
QSharedPointer<Base> base...

QSharedPointer<Derived> derived = qSharedPointerDynamicCast<Derived>( base );
```

There are also equivalents for static_cast (as in silico showed), qobject_cast and const_cast. Pick your poison.